# Unable to run the app on hosted server

Tags: codeigniter

I have just installed Ci framework and tried on my local some basics according to the tutorial.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

On local machine, everything was OK and page was displayed.

Than I upload project to the server (I am using wedos web hosting where I already have som web which is working correctly) but this is not working for the application which I copied it here. When I type the URL I got 404 error.

On my webhosting service I have **www** folder where i put my index.html file. Than when i type **www.mydomain.eu** I get this index.html file. Than I have subfolder **www/folder/index.html** Than when i type **www.mydomain.eu/folder** i get this page so it is ok.

Than i have **www/folder2/here i unzip CodeIgniter framework** and when i type **www.mydomain.eu/folder2**, 404 Page Not Found appears. The error is not general error from browser but generated from the CI framework.

I have created my own controler in application/controllers/mycontroller.php

```
<?php

class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = ‘enter_form’)
{

  $data[‘title’] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

  $this->load->view(‘templates/header’, $data);
  $this->load->view(‘pages/’.$page, $data);
  $this->load->view(‘templates/footer’, $data);
}
}
```

And I have following structure of views:

views/pages/enter_form.php

views/templates/header.php and footer.php

And the following settings:

1)  $config[‘base_url’] = ‘’; but I have tried ‘http://mydomain.eu/’ and ‘http://mydomain.eu/www/’ or ‘http://mydomain.eu/www/folder2/’

2)  $route[‘default_controller’] = ‘mycontroller/view’;

$route[’(:any)’] = ‘mycontroller/view/$1’;

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like there is either a configuration issue or a rewrite issue going on. Do you have a .htaccess file in your CI root folder where your index.php file lives? Seeing that you are depending on the CI to pick up any uri and reroute it to a specific route, this might be the issue. I've ran into issues with this before on different hosts. Make sure mod rewrite is enabled and make sure your .htaccess is something similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You mean the .htaccess file in the application directory? Cause in the root directory **www/folder2/** (from my example above) I have no .htaccess file.

In the **application** folder (folder where folders like views, controllers etc. are present) i have .htaccess file with the following string Deny from all

Comment: in the www/folder2/ folder there should be a .htaccess file. CI puts .htaccess files in the application directory so you cant direct link to a controller/config file etc. So, yes put it in the same directory as your main front controller (index.php) file. this tells the server to route all requests to the index.php file.

Comment: OK, I did it. I put .htaccess file with your definition from above and when I try www.mydomain.eu/folder2 I getthe following error: The requested URL /index.php/ was not found on this server.

Comment: I also found .htaccess file in the **www** folder with the following definition:

    `RewriteEngine On`

    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$`
    `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d`
    `RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]`

    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$`
    `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d`
    RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like the typo somewhere, because when I used the default CI welcome pages, it works. So I will try to find the typo myself and i will see...